# Can not detect objects in xml - Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I create a button on main layout then it's unable to be detected in main activity.
Please let me know how do I fix this issue.

Note: Android Studio 4.1.1.1 and Kotlin

[image]

[image]

Comment: Read this: https://medium.com/better-programming/why-are-kotlin-synthetics-deprecated-and-what-are-the-alternatives-5c2b087dda1c

Comment: forpas// Didn't know that the news and just read the articles you provided. I've resolved it by adding kotlin-android-extenesions in gradle myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[image]You cannot access the button directly. You need to attach it to a variable with access to the button.

```
  val newButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnHelp);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(){
        println(2+2)
    }
```

The first line creates a variable and attaches it to the button ID.
The second line connects the click listener.